How many 5-digit numbers do not contain prime digits on consecutive positions.
Example: 12345 is invalid because it contains 2,3 in consecutive positions, but 26983 is valid as it does not have any prime numbers in consecutive positions.
My approach
Let the numbers be of the form abcde
Prime digits: 2, 3, 5, 7
Non-prime digits: 0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9
If a, c and e are prime, we have:
4 * 6 * 4 * 6 * 4 = 2304
If a and c or a and d or a and e are prime, we have:
4 * 6 * 4 * 6 * 6 = 3456
3 * 3456 = 10368
If b and d or b and e or c and e are prime, we have:
5 * 4 * 6 * 4 * 6 = 2880
3 * 2880 = 8640
If a is prime, we have:
4 * 6 * 6 * 6 * 6 = 5184
If either of b or c or d or e is prime, we have:
5 * 4 * 6 * 6 * 6 = 4320
4 * 4320 = 17280
If none is prime, we have:
5 * 6 * 6 * 6 * 6 = 6480
So, in total we have:
2304 + 10368 + 8640 + 5184 + 17280 + 6480 = 50256

Is there a better way to solve this kind of problems?


Let $\ p_n\ $ be the number of $n$-digit integers containing no consecutive prime digits and ending in a prime, and $\ q_n\ $ be the number of $n$-digit integers containing no consecutive prime digits and ending in a non-prime.  Then
\begin{align}
p_1&=4\\
q_1&=5\\
p_n&=4q_{n-1}\ \ \text{and}\\
q_n&=6\big(p_{n-1}+q_{n-1}\big)\\
&=6q_{n-1}+24q_{n-2}
\end{align}
for $\ n\ge2\ $ if we artificially take $\ q_0\ $ to be $1$.  The solution of this recurrence is given by
$$
q_n=\frac{(2+\sqrt{33})(3+\sqrt{33})^n-(2-\sqrt{33})(3-\sqrt{33})^n}{2\sqrt{33}}\ ,
$$
and the total number of $5$-digit numbers with no consecutive prime digits is
\begin{align}
q_5+p_5&=q_5+4q_4\\
&=50256\ ,
\end{align}
thus confirming your calculation. Alternatively, you can step the recursion by using the matrix equation
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{p_n\\q_n}&=\pmatrix{0&4\\6&6}\pmatrix{p_{n-1}\\q_{n-1}}\\
&=\pmatrix{0&4\\6&6}^{n-1}\pmatrix{p_1\\q_1}\\
&=\pmatrix{0&4\\6&6}^{n-1}\pmatrix{4\\5}\ .
\end{align}
With $\ n=5\ ,$ this gives us
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{p_5\\q_5}&=\pmatrix{0&4\\6&6}^4\pmatrix{4\\5}\\
&=\pmatrix{1440&2016\\3024&4464}\pmatrix{4\\5}\\
&=\pmatrix{15840\\34416}\,
\end{align}
and $\ p_5+q_5=15840+34416=50256\ .$
Additional remarks
In response to your final question, I'll point out that this technique can be generalised to a method for finding the total number of words of a given length in any regular language.  If $\ (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)\ $ is a (deterministic) finite-state automaton that accepts the language (in the notation of the Wikipedia article at the preceding link), $\ N_q(n)\ $ the number of sequences of length $\ n\ $ that will drive the automaton from the starting state $\ q_0\in Q\ $ to the state $\ q\in Q\ ,$ $\ \nu(n)\ $ the $\ |
Q|\times1\ $ column vector whose $\ q^\text{th}\ $ entry is $\ N_q(n)\ ,$ and $\ D\ $ the $\ |Q|\times|Q|\ $ matrix whose $\ pq^\text{th}\ $ entry, $\ D_{pq}\ ,$ for $\ p,q\in Q\ $ is given by
$$
D_{pq}=\big|\big\{s\in\Sigma\,\big|\,\delta(q,s)=p\big\}\big|\ ,
$$
then
\begin{align}
\nu(n)&=D\nu(n-1)\\
&=D^n\nu(0)
\end{align}
with
$$
\nu_q(0)=\cases{1&if $\ q=q_0$\\0&otherwise}\ .
$$
The number of words of length $\ n\ $ belonging to the language is then equal to
$$
\sum_{q\in F}\nu_q(n)\ .
$$

We can use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.
Let $A_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$, be the set of five-digit positive integers with prime digits in positions $i$ and $i + 1$, where we count positions from left to right.
The number of five-digit positive integers with no two consecutive prime digits is the difference of the number of five-digit positive integers and the number of five-digit positive integers with at least two consecutive prime digits.
There are $9 \cdot 10^4$ five-digit positive integers since there are nine choices for the ten thousands digit and $10$ choices for each of the remaining digits.  From these, we must subtract those five-digit positive integers with at least two consecutive prime digits, that is,
\begin{align*}
& 9 \cdot 10^4 - |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4|\\
& = 9 \cdot 10^4 - \left[\sum_{i = 1}^{4} |A_i| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 4} |A_i \cap A_j| + \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq 4} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\right]\\
& = 9 \cdot 10^4 - \sum_{i = 1}^{4} |A_i| + \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 4} |A_i \cap A_j| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq 4} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\\
& = 9 \cdot 10^4 - |A_1| - |A_2| - |A_3| - |A_4|\\
& \quad + |A_1 \cap A_2| + |A_1 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_4| + |A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_2 \cap A_4| + |A_3 \cap A_4|\\
& \qquad - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| - |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| - |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\\
& \qquad\qquad + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|
\end{align*}
$|A_1|$:  If the first two positions are filled with primes, there are $4$ choices for each of the first two positions and $10$ choices for each of the remaining three positions.  Thus, $|A_1| = 4^2 \cdot 10^3$.
$|A_2|$:  If the second and third positions are filled with primes, there are $9$ choices for the leading digit, $4$ choices for each of the second and third positions, and $10$ choices for each of the remaining two positions.  Hence, $|A_2| = 9 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 10^2$.
By symmetry, $|A_2| = |A_3| = |A_4|$.
$|A_1 \cap A_2|$:  The first three positions must be filled with primes.  Thus, there are four choices for each of the first three positions and $10$ choices for each of the last two positions.  Thus, $|A_1 \cap A_2| = 4^3 \cdot 10^2$.
$|A_1 \cap A_3|$:  The first four positions must be filled with primes.  Thus, there are four choices for each of the first four positions and $10$ choices for the fifth position.  Thus, $|A_1 \cap A_3| = 4^4 \cdot 10$.
By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_3| = |A_1 \cap A_4|$.
$|A_2 \cap A_3|$:  The second, third, and fourth positions must be filled with primes.  Therefore, there are nine choices for the leading digit, four choices for each of the next three positions, and $10$ choices for the last position.  Therefore, $|A_2 \cap A_3| = 9 \cdot 4^3 \cdot 10$.
$|A_2 \cap A_4|$:  The last four positions must be filled with primes. Therefore, there are nine choices for the leading digit and four choices for each of the remaining four positions.  Hence, $|A_2 \cap A_4| = 9 \cdot 4^4$.
$|A_3 \cap A_4|$:  The last three positions must be filled with primes.  Therefore, there are nine choices for the leading digit, $10$ choices for the second position, and four choices for each of the last three positions.  Hence, $|A_3 \cap A_4| = 9 \cdot 10 \cdot 4^3$.
$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$: The first four positions must be filled with primes.  Thus, there are four choices for each of the first four positions and $10$ choices for the last position.  Therefore, $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 4^4 \cdot 10$.
$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4|$: All five positions must be filled with primes, leaving four choices for each position.  Hence, $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| = 4^5$.
By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| = |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$.
$|A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$:  The last four positions must be filled with primes.  There are nine choices for the leading digit and four choices for each of the remaining four positions.  Hence, $|A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 9 \cdot 4^4$.
$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$: All five positions must be filled with primes, leaving four choices for each position.  Hence, $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 4^5$.
Therefore, the number of five-digit positive integers in which no two consecutive digits are prime is
\begin{align*}
& 9 \cdot 10^4\\
& \quad - 4^2 \cdot 10^3 - 3 \cdot 9 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 10^2\\
& \quad + 4^3 \cdot 10^2 + 2 \cdot 4^4 \cdot 10 + 9 \cdot 4^3 \cdot 10 + 9 \cdot 4^4 + 9 \cdot 10 \cdot 4^3\\
& \quad - 4^4 \cdot 10 - 2 \cdot 4^5 - 9 \cdot 4^4\\
& \quad + 4^5\\ 
& = 50,256
\end{align*}
